# Session variable in WCF application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I need to use or stimulate a very simple session object inside my WCF app.

I simply need to store some values at the beginning of a call and I need access to these values while I go through some different methods of my service.

Asp.NET session would be very ideal to use for this so I need to find out what is available on a WCF app for storing such values.

Note: this is just a per call session, I don't need to retain this session between different calls from the client to service and such..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing (custom context that is retained for the life of a single request) is more like `HttpContext.Items` than an ASP.NET Session.

WCF does have a class called `OperationContext` that is similar to `HttpContext`.  It doesn't have an `Items` property for custom context, but [this  blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20140312141611/http://hyperthink.net/blog/a-simple-ish-approach-to-custom-context-in-wcf/) describes a technique you can use to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Joe The link is broken. Can you provide more information? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to do a couple of things.

Set **aspNetCompatibilityEnabled = true** on your host (inside system.ServiceModel | serviceHostingEnvironment)

The service (**not the contract**) - should be attributed with:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```

Finally you have you have to set allowCookies on your binding to true.

```
<basicHttpBinding>
 <binding name="SessionBinding" allowCookies="true">
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Just curious, are you certain you *need* session?

Comment: the <binding name="SessionBinding" allowCookies="true"> should be set in the service I assume?

Comment: <binding name="SessionBinding" allowCookies="true"> should be set in client